# how to add button to lightning list view

Tags: salesforce, apex, lightning, salesforce-lightning

is it possible to add new action along with edit/delete values in drop down near every object(image below)
[image]

I followed this topic [topick](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000I5vQQAS)

the only decision I have come up with is like in this article [click here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/09/take-the-first-steps-ways-you-can-replace-javascript-buttons.html)
since winter 17 relese we can add button with vf page action only in lightning  on the header of list view.
 1. Create your Visualforce page.
 2. Create a custom button that references your Visualforce page.
 3. Add the action to your list view.

its looks like this:

[image]

So, is it possible to add action to the dropdown like in first picture?

Comment: No its not possible with Standard layouts, You have to build your own custom layout.

Comment: @chinmayahd and how do we create our own custom layout. Any resource, idea on this